# Javascript replace() regexp: nesting modifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a concatenated file path to a document on a server, e.g.

```
http://test:1234@192.168.0.12:5555/../test/directory/../name/sub/sub/../../file.js
```

and for some unknown reason the XHR request I send out to that "URL" returns error 404, while Chrome, when I give him the same path, makes

```
http://test:1234@192.168.0.12:5555/test/name/file.js
```

from it and returns the document okay. Now I am searching for a javascript regexp search/replace that can "clean" the path.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
console.log(
    "http://test:1234@192.168.0.12:5555/../test/directory/../name/sub/sub/../../file.js"
    .replace(/([^\/])\/[^\/]*\/..\//g,'$1/')
);
```

The regexp works except for nested matches: `/sub/dir/../../` is replaced to `/sub/../`, should be `/`.

Is there a nesting modifier available?

Comment: You could keep re-running the _RegExp_ in a loop until you see no more changes `while (bar !== (foo = bar.replace(re))) bar = foo;`

Comment: Please give some feedback if my answer had worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *try* this approach:

```js
var url = "http://test:1234@192.168.0.12:5555/../test/directory/../name/sub/sub/../../file.js";

var new_url = url.replace(/(^.*?(?=\/\.\.))|(?:\/\.\.)+(\/[^\/]+)|./g, '$1$2');

document.write(new_url);
```

Regex with colors [here](https://regex101.com/r/gQ1oU4/2).

Hope it helps.